# Inconsistent lsof output

Tags: lsof

I am running few java processes on a machine and I wanted an exact count of number of open files and what kind those files.

First of all, running `sudo lsof` takes a long time.

```
[user@host]:~$ time sudo lsof > lsof.txt

real    1m5.920s
user    0m27.152s
sys 0m38.100s
```

Finding out the number of files opened by java processes:

```
[user@host]:~$ grep -e "^java" lsof.txt -c
2565341
```

which is unusually high.

If I try to arrive at the same number by filtering `lsof`'s output using `-c` flag, I get a totally different answer and `lsof` takes very little time compared to the first command

```
[user@host]:~$ time sudo lsof -c java | wc -l
4465

real    0m0.139s
user    0m0.052s
sys 0m0.068s
```

Answer (score 2):

The speed inconsistency comes from the fact that sockets are also files, and other network related stuff like doing a stat() on an NFS. You can run `lsof -b` which will skip those operations.

As for the differencies in line numbers, well, you have to examine the result yourself. Sometimes it helps if you sort the result then compare it like so:

```
    sort lsof.txt > lsof-full-sorted.txt
    diff lsof-full-sorted.txt lsof-filtered-sorted.txt
```

(In my example lsof-filtered-sorted.txt refers to the output of `lsof -c java|sort`)

Also, midnight commander has a nice file compare functionality based on diff, which is easier to read than the diff output.